# extract data from Google spread sheets using imcaro

Tags: google-sheets, imacros

I'm trying to extract a cell value from a Google spreadsheet using imacro script.

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13akuXU0cp047_6VFdtUgdn2fKfhPilF_hPHrnTNV164/edit#gid=883874257) is the spread sheet I'm working on.

And I need to get the Cell 'A1' value.

Below is my try, and it is not working.

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:https://www.ebay.com* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible (simplest) ways is to use Google Query Language for requesting necessary data and extract them afterwards. Something like this:

```
URL GOTO=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13akuXU0cp047_6VFdtUgdn2fKfhPilF_hPHrnTNV164/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20A%20limit%201
TAG XPATH="//tr[last()]/td" EXTRACT=TXT
```

Keep in mind that your spreadsheet must be shared in this case.

Comment: It's nice to hear!